# Support needed for implementation of the gate2mysql Plugin

Tags: sql, gate

I have a problem and would appreciate if anybody can help me with that.

So here is the task that I am struggling with. I have to annotate a whole document through GATE (General Architecture for Text Engineering). This itself is working quite well. But here comes the tricky part:
I have to write a programm that automatically reads the files into GATE, sends them through the annotation process and saves the results as XML. Unfortunately I cannot write programms so I am stuck here. **Does anybody have an idea of how to do this?** My professor said that it should be easily possible within 20 lines of code.

Since I told him that I cannot do this he also gave a second option of solving this, but this doesn't really get me any further:
I can also download the gate2mysql plugin (done) and set up and SQL server on my computer (done). Then those two should be linked (no idea how to do that) and write inside of that plugin a structured way of how to save the files as SQL (a table with 2 columns: old text - annotated text). Here I am totally stuck with the configuration of the plugin. Whenever I want to set up a "New gate2mysql" a configuration window pops up and no matter how i fill it, an error occurs. If a picture of this helps, I can of course provide that. It says "Unhandled Error. java.lang.NullPointerException". So I guess the path that I enter might be wrong. The columns in the configuration window that I have to fill out are: banco, porta, senha, servidor, usario. No idea why they are Spanish, though... So I have no idea what to fill in at banco, the port is automatically filled in, even though I dont know if it is the right one, so I just disabled the Windows Firewall to pass this step. I guess that the Error message pops up, because I dont fill in the right pass to my server. But I do not really know, how the server file that this plugin is looking for might be named. Just linking it to the folder does not help.
 **So does anybody have experience about how to set up this plugin and work with it in GATE?**

Any help is welcome because I am starting to get frustrated and have literally no idea about how to proceed.

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your professor was a bit incorrect saying about 20 lines of code.. But good example of what the task implemented you can find at  [GATE processing example](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/javadoc/src-html/sheffield/examples/BatchProcessApp.html)

From my point of view using mysql plugin is more complicated way...